# C# serial port problem - too simple to fail, but

Tags: c#, mono, serial-port

Ok, this should be dirt simple. I'm trying to read charactes from a serial device. It's such that if I send a space character, it echos back a string of numbers and EOL. That's it.

I'm using Unity 3.3 (.Net 2.0 support), and the 'serial port' is a Prolific serial-to-USB adaptor. BTW: Using Hyperterminal, it all works perfectly, so I know it's not driver nor hardware.

I can open the port ok. It seems I can send my space with port.Write(" "); But if I even TRY to call ReadChar, ReadByte, or ReadLine (like polling), it freezes up until I unplug the USB, and my console output shows nothing (exceptions were caught).

So instead I set up a DataReceviedHandler, but it's never called.

I've read some posts where people have done just this type of thing with Arduinos etc. (this is not an Arduino but hey), using nothing more than ReadLine. Their code does not work for me (and no answers thus far from those authors).

So, any tips? Do I need to use a different thread? If you know any Unity (Mono) coding, any tips along those lines greatly appreciated.

This code a mashup from http://plikker.com/?p=163 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx#Y537

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System;

public class SerialTest : MonoBehaviour {

 SerialPort stream;

 void Start () {
  try {
   stream = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
   stream.Parity = Parity.None;
   stream.StopBits = StopBits.One;
   stream.DataBits = 8;
   stream.Handshake = Handshake.None;
   stream.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceviedHandler);


   stream.Open();
   Debug.Log("opened ok"); // it DOES open ok!
  } catch (Exception e){
   Debug.Log("Error opening port "+e.ToString()); // I never see this message
  }
 }

 void Update () { // called about 60 times/second
  try {
   // Read serialinput from COM3
   // if this next line is here, it will hang, I don't even see the startup message
   Debug.Log(stream.ReadLine());
   // Note: I've also tried ReadByte and ReadChar and the same problem, it hangs
  } catch (Exception e){
   Debug.Log("Error reading input "+e.ToString());
  }
 }

 private static void DataReceviedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
  SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender; // It never gets here!
  string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
  Debug.Log("Data Received:");
  Debug.Log(indata);
 }

 void OnGUI() // simple GUI
 {
   // Create a button that, when pressed, sends the 'ping'
   if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,10,100,20), "Send"))
 stream.Write(" ");
 }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code, in particular the code where you open the device.

Comment: Can you try the other way around, can you verify that your program can actually send things out of this port?

Comment: Using Serial Port Monitor, looks like my 'ping' chars to get sent, or at least SPM sees them. But no data comes in. I did it with Hyperterminal and it looks similar except that data comes in. What's the diff? Anyone know how to read those logs?

Comment: Now that you posted your code: Why do you read from the serial port in the Update method, and yet expect to see something in the event handler? Is Update called 60 times per second, even if the last call did not finish? Does it work if you disable the Update loop? And finally, did you just try it with plain .NET on Windows, just to be sure?

Comment: I was trying both to see if either works. I see that Mono doesn't support the event, I'll remove it. I have not tried plain .NET yet, that was next. As I understand, a Read call will block, that seems to be a real problem. I also tried looking for 'data available' before calling Read and that hung too. Sounds like I either need another thread, but would a coroutine help?

Comment: There are plenty of relevant solutions in this section. But as for me, I personally use [Serial Port Monitor](http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/), which works perfect for me. But I must admit that there are plenty alternatives when it comes to monitor virtual portsas Serial Port Monitor or comOcom. But I've got a chance to use them, so my recommendation for solving this problem is Serial Port Monitor by Eltima.

Comment: I had similar issue I resolved it by myPort.NewLine = "\n" (it's default value is actually "\r\n" which prevents ReadLine() method to work and lead to TimeoutException).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are opening the right port, using correct settings. Here is an example of how you could configure it:

```
serial = new SerialPort();

serial.ReadBufferSize = 8192;
serial.WriteBufferSize = 128;

serial.PortName = "COM1";
serial.BaudRate = 115200;
serial.Parity = Parity.None;
serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;

// attach handlers
// (appears to be broken in some Mono versions?)
serial.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;
serial.Disposed += SerialPort_Disposed;

serial.Open();
```

I recommend the open source [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) terminal, it has a rich set of features and can help you debug. Try writing a byte manually using such software, and if it works, then the problem is in your program. Otherwise it might be a driver problem (but more likely it isn't).

**[Edit]**

Calling [`SerialPort.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is actually supposed to block the thread until [`SerialPort.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is received. Also `ReadChar` and `ReadByte` will hang until at least one byte is received. You need to make sure that you are actually receiving characters from the other side, and you won't be receiving them if your app is stuck and cannot send the space.

Since I never used Unity, I am not sure how `Update` is called, but I am presuming it's fired on a foreground thread in regular intervals (otherwise your app wouldn't freeze).

The example that you linked ([Arduino and Unity example](http://plikker.com/?p=163)) shows that Arduino is sending the data continuously, and that is why their `Update` method is constantly receiving data (no space character needs to be sent towards the device). If they unplug the device, their app will hang just as well.

Well, maybe not, because in .NET 1.1, default value for `ReadTimeout` was not infinite, like it is in .NET 2.0.

So, what you can do is:

**a.** Set the `ReadTimeout` property to a reasonable value. Default in .NET 2.0 is InfiniteTimeout, which doesn't suit your needs. Cons: your update method will still hang for a while on each call, but not infinitely.

**b.** Someone said that events are not implemented in MONO SerialPort, so I guess using `DataReceived` only is not an option.

**c.** Move your **sending logic** to the `Update` method also, so that you don't read data at all, until it's time to read it:

```
private volatile bool _shouldCommunicate = false;
void Update ()
{
  if (_shouldCommunicate) // this is a flag you set in "OnGui"
  {
     try {
       stream.Write(" ");
       Debug.Log(stream.ReadLine());
     } catch (Exception e){
       Debug.Log("Error reading input "+e.ToString());
     }
  }
}

void OnGUI() // simple GUI
{
   if (GUI.Button (new Rect(10,10,100,20), "Send"))
      _shouldCommunicate = true;
}
```

Note that, if your device is not sending data, it will also block at `stream.ReadLine()`, so make sure your `ReadTimeout` is set to a reasonable value. You will also want to stop sending at some point, but I leave that to you.

**d.** Send the space in `OnGui` like you are doing now, but always check if there is data in your buffer before reading it:

```
void Update () { // called about 60 times/second
 try {
   // call our new method
   Debug.Log(ReadLineNonBlocking());
 } catch (Exception e){
  Debug.Log("Error reading input "+e.ToString());
 }
}

private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string ReadLineNonBlocking()
{
    int len = stream.BytesToRead;
    if (len == 0)
        return "";

    // read the buffer
    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, len);
    sb.Append(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));

    // got EOL?
    if (sb.Length < 2 ||
        sb[sb.Length-2] != '\r' ||
        sb[sb.Length-1] != '\n')
        return ""; 

    // if we are here, we got both EOL chars
    string entireLine = sb.ToString();
    sb.Length = 0;
    return entireLine;
 }
```

Disclaimer: this is directly out of my head, untested, so there may be some syntax errors which I am sure you will handle.

Comment: Like I said, I did use Hyperterminal and it works there, but RealTerm sounds good. I'll try what you suggested. I had set port,baud,parity,stop in the SerialPort constructor, and handshake=none before Opening. Open works fine. It's the Read, Readline that 'hang' and DataReceived never getting called that bugs me. Perhaps its buffers etc.

Comment: Ok, tried this, but it doesn't like DiscardNull nor ReceivedBytesThreshold (I'm on .NET 2.0), commented those out. Still not working.

Comment: [ReceivedBytesThreshold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y228) and [DiscardNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.discardnull%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) actually exist in .NET 2.0, did you mean .NET 1.1? But their defaults are actually `1` and `false`, so it doesn't matter (I just copied this from an older project without checking).

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I'm actually using Unity (3.3), which uses Mono (2.6.3) and .NET 2.0. Using MonoDevelop I set a breakpoint after the port is opened to see what's what, and the debugger itself said that some of these thing do not have a valid object, or something like that. Which I thought odd for things that should be just numbers or bits. I tried reading BytesToRead but it didn't like that either (will post error when I get back to my dev machine)

Comment: Using short timeout, alternate thread, and sending the 'ping' often, also setting NewLine to the oddball reverse string this thing has, all wrapped it up. Thanks so much for your help. Everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Events are not implemented in Mono `SerialPort` class, so you won't get any notifications, you have to perform (blocking) read explicitly. Other possible problem - I'm not sure how Unity Behaviours work, are you certain all methods accessing the `SerialPort` are invoked on the same thread? And you are not disposing you port object, this will also cause problems.

Comment: I'll remove the event handler. All same thread, should I use a different one? Or coroutine (I didn't realize Read blocked) I also tried checking BytesToRead before calling Read, but this also seemed to hang. I'll try again, maybe I had a typo. Thanks for tips!

Comment: Exactly, and the detail of differences between original C# and Mono implementation of SerialPort is described here : http://www.mono-project.com/archived/howtosystemioports/#limitations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the configuration of the serial port. It is important not only to check for BaudRate or StopBits. Also you should configure DTR, RTS, Handshake, everything. This is important cause maybe another program set some ugly values and the configuration must be explicitly set at every start or some settings of the old connection can run you into trouble.

Also maybe take a look into one of these tools:

- [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/)
- [Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/)

They can help you to stub your serial interface or to take a deeper look into the connection. Also maybe try to talk to your serial device by using [HyperTerminal](http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal/) or some similar tool that's proven to work.

Comment: I have used HyperTerminal as stated, works fine, but these tools sound promising, thank you

Comment: Using Serial Port Monitor, looks like my 'ping' chars to get sent, or at least SPM sees them. But no data comes in. I did it with Hyperterminal and it looks similar except that data comes in. Diff is HypTerm 'set current event mask' (??) and the sent chars are children of (preceded by?) 'Wait for event' and IRP_MJ_READ (then it writes my ping char), then IRP_MJ_READs happend and there the data is. How do I get that to happen in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with Mono, upgrading to 2.6.7 helped.

Comment: Unity may be on 2.6 (not sure what sub release after that if any). From which version did you upgrade?

Comment: It was 2.6.3 or 2.6.4. Well, won't Unity be upgraded? Maybe you should contact them.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix data event and blocking read. What do you expect to happen if data arrives? That both the read method and the event should get the same received data?

You should also read about:

- CTS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232_RTS/CTS#RTS.2FCTS_handshaking
- DTR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Terminal_Ready

Small serial port tutorial describing all states: http://www.wcscnet.com/Tutorials/SerialComm/Page1.htm

Comment: Thanks. I was trying both to see if either would produce a result, will remove the event handler. My hardware expects no handshake, but the serial log (for Hyperterminal) seemed to imply that it might help (?) Thanks for links

Answer (score 0):

The standard c# System.IO.Pots.SerialPort sucks big time. I suggest to give [RJCP.DLL.SerialPortStream library](https://github.com/jcurl/RJCP.DLL.SerialPortStream) a try. Synchronous read/write is super easy with this delightful library too, no need to jump through the loops with delegate and listeners.