# How to send command to RS232 serial port?

Tags: c#, console, serial-port, firmware, .net-4.8

I recently got a sas expander card.

The one who gave card to me said:

It has a firmware on the chip and it can show sensor's temperature.

He wants me to develop a `C#` `Console app` to execute the firmware.

I didn't know the firmware source code looks like.

But it could be executed by `PuTTy` and it's connection was via `RS232` Serial Port.

`PuTTy` connection setting:

[image]

[image]

After I click `Open`,press `Enter` and type command `sys`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I try in my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace SerialPortExample
{
    class SerialPortProgram
    {
        // Create the serial port with basic settings
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           
           
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            if(mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            { 
                string str= "Enter";
                mySerialPort.Write(str);
 
            }
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            
            Console.ReadLine();
            
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
            Console.Write(indata);
        }


    }
}
```

What my code execute:

[image]

What is the problem with my code?

How can I execute firmware via `RS232` and interact like `PuTTy` have done?

My Console app is using `.Net Framework 4.7.2`.

Comment: The term "execute firmware" is misleading here (it sounds like you want to flash a new firmware onto the device or possibly load code into RAM and execute it on the fly), that's why I updated the title of your question. The firmware is executed the moment you apply power to the card. What you want to do is interact with the (already running) firmware through the serial console interface it exposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the string `Enter` (like typing <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>). You should probably send the <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> *key*, which is represented on a terminal with the ASCII code 13, i.e. `\r` in a C# string.

Also you don't yet send any actual command. Try something like `counters\r` or `sys\r`.

(You currently receive the `Enter` back as response because that's what you sent out, and the card echoes any incoming characters so it can be used like a shell without blind typing. There is no other response yet because from the card's perspective you basically started typing the (invalid) command `Enter` but haven't yet submitted it with the <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> key.)

Also I'd suggest adding the event listener for received data before sending any data, otherwise there would be a race condition in which the card could be responding before you even set up your listener and you would lose part of the data.

---

Additional note: Using the `DataRecieved` event may not even be desirable in your case.

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0):

> The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received. Use the `BytesToRead` property to determine how much data is left to be read in the buffer.

This means that **your `DataReceived` event may not even fire at all** if there wasn't enough data sent in total yet (it may fire some time later with all the data at once) - but if you quit your program before that, you will never see.

As suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/206dd038-ce73-4e98-bff4-25ca9116bbeb/serialport-datareceived-response-time?forum=netfxbcl) (emphasis mine):

> Here is my general approach:
>
> Use event-driven (DataReceived) code for streaming data.  That is, where data is delivered at regular intervals, without specific associated commands that originate from your application.
>
> **Use polling for Command/Response protocols.**  These might involve a thread the you create to poll, but more frequently would be simple loops that may or may not block other operations until they complete.

So, it would be recommended to use one of the `Read` methods instead (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)). There is also `ReadTo` and `ReadLine` which you may find useful. You may choose to use `ReadTo(" bp1 >")` for instance.

Comment: I changed my code on console app. The execute result comes up bp1>.After I press ``enter`` key, the app closed. How to continuously accept command and receive command result?just keep adding mySerialPort.DataReceived event?

Comment: Adding the event handler once will suffice. Just don't quit your program - for example if you want to query `counters` every second, create a loop which sleeps for 1s and then sends `counters\r`, over and over.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The question's word ``continuously`` is ``synchronously``. I just got sys command result but it doesn't show up. I have to close app and reopen it.The result would show up.

Comment: This would be a different question - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026042/wait-for-response-from-the-serial-port-and-then-send-next-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850011/c-sharp-waiting-for-the-data-on-serial-port

Comment: Also just to make sure: You are sending the enter key (`\r`) _after_ sending the command, right? Not the other way round? You said you got `bp1>`  but no `sys` response, which would suggest that you sent an empty command (like just `\r` without command before it), that's why I'm asking... and "shows up next time" would also make sense then if it would submit the previous run's command at that point... Make sure you send `sys\r` and not `\rsys`.

Comment: Well, I just use ``mySerialPort.Write("sys");``without ``\r`` and result would show in the  reopening app. If I use ``mySerialPort.Write("sys\r")``, there will no response even I reopened it. Thanks for the link question. I will do some research.

Comment: I added information into my answer.